# Microsoft Identity Provider from Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have two applications in Azure:

1. Azure Service running a web application. This application uses Microsoft Identity provider for authentication.
2. An Azure Function

I'd like to make calls from (2) to (1), but of course am running into authentication issues. I'd like to pass some sort of application / service account credentials from the Azure Function to the Web application with each request.

The documentation / examples don't seem to address this situation. What is the best way to accomplish this?